# What does autorotation mask mean?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I was going through this text:

"If you want the view Controller being displayed by  UINavigationController to determine the autorotation mask, subclass UINavigationController and override it:..."

They put this in return of supportedInterfaceOrientations-

```
return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
```

I want to ask what does "mask" mean when a person says autorotation mask? and what does this code mean??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In computer science, a mask is data that is used for bitwise operations, particularly in a bit field. -Wikipedia

Basically what is happening is your device has 4 settings, Portrait ,Landscape Left, Landscape Right, and Portrait upside down.  Now to allow for multiple settings,  you need to set up some kind of flag system. Basic Visual Description

Orientation I want is [X]Portrait [ ]Landscape Left [ ]Landscape Right [ ]Portrait upside down.

Basically this says I want to only support portrait orientation.

so to translate this into computer code, we use binary operations

orientation = 1 , 0 , 0 , 0

But this is still not fit for a computer,  we need to make this into a byte format.

we shift the bits so that we can compact the bits into the byte, 
with portrait being 1 << 3 LL being 1 << 2 LR being 1 << 1 and PUD being 1 <<0.

We can then combine them with the following operation

orientation = (1<<3) | (0<<2) | (0<<1) | (0<<0)

which becomes

orientation = 1000 (this is binary, not one thousand)

which is now in a readable format that the computer can read.

It will check if each bit is active, and then support it.

Now these values are already defined for you,  so you do not need to do the math to get them.  So you would just say:

```
orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
```

Now to actually use this code it is as simple as:

```
override  func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait

}
```

To get your autorotation,  it will look like this:

```
override  func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
    }
}
```

We want to do it this way because the idea is, if a person is playing a game, and they get a call,  they may answer the call with the phone upside down,  so we do not want phones to be able to support upside down portrait